# Recreating a plot from Fundamentals of Data Visualization

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to recreate this plot:[Fundamentals of Data Visualization](https://serialmentor.com/dataviz/boxplots-violins.html#boxplots-violins-horizontal). See also below with the screenshot. I have searched the GitHub page [link](https://github.com/clauswilke/dataviz) but I cannot find it. Can someone create a plot like a book with many distributions along the horizontal axis?

The plot from the book: 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `geom_density_ridges` function from the `ggridges` package in addition to `ggplot2`:

The code to make the basis for what you want could look like this. Of course, you can tweak hundreds of details.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)

ggplot(lincoln_weather, aes(x = `Mean Temperature [F]`, y = `Month`)) +
  geom_density_ridges(rel_min_height = 0.05, fill = "blue", color = "grey") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "mean temperature (°F)" )
```

yielding the following plot:

[image]